# 'The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties' on identical paths

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce

I'm having a strange error with Umbraco/uCommerce, I built a support library and suddenly I'm getting a strange error preventing compilation.

> Error 9   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   'uCommerce_Boilerplate.Web.Controllers.ExtensionFunctions.ToDescription(System.Enum)'
>   and
>   'uCommerce_Boilerplate.Web.Controllers.ExtensionFunctions.ToDescription(System.Enum)'

I have one file that contains several features, and this is the snippet prompting the error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using UCommerce;
using UCommerce.EntitiesV2;
using UCommerce.Infrastructure;
using UCommerce.Transactions;
using UCommerce.Transactions.Payments;
using UCommerce.Transactions.Payments.Dibs;

namespace uCommerce_Boilerplate.Web.Controllers
{
    public static class ExtensionFunctions
    {
        public static string ToDescription(this Enum value)
        {
            var da = (DescriptionAttribute[])(value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString())).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            return da.Length > 0 ? da[0].Description : value.ToString();
        }
    }
    public static class SupportLib
    {
        public enum MethodName
        {
            [Description("Invoice")] Invoice = 1,
        }
        public static void RunOrder(MethodName methodName = MethodName.Invoice)
        {
            // The methodName.ToDescription() is throwing the error
            PaymentMethod method = getPaymentMethod(methodName.ToDescription());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is this method stored? In it's own assembly?

Comment: I hit enter errorously posting the question alittle early. I have one file called SupportLib.cs located in the Controllers folder, and it contains both parts of code, it also contains other support classes that don't throw errors.

Comment: Does your assembly contain `UserControl` classes that you've dragged from the VS Toolbox onto a Designer surface?

Comment: maybe, how would that play a role? im only setting up the class on the backend, the code is not used by anything yet

Comment: The Designer automatically adds a reference to the current assembly whenever a UserControl is dragged onto a surface. Your assembly is depending on itself.

Comment: Hmm, well this is a razor MVC thing so you cant really drag anything to a designer. I just noticed the error really only pops up after a successful compile. meaning that I can move `ExtensionFunctions` out to a different file compile once and then errors move back compile once and then errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have a circular reference in your assembly references which is why the method call is suddenly ambiguous.

As you described in the question comments you have used `UserControls` from that assembly within itself, the VS Designer might have added a reference of the `UserControl's` containing assembly to itself as this is what sometimes happens when you use a `UserControl` from the VS Toolbox.

Comment: yes its definitely a circular issue, the class is just standing there and generating 7 errors on on error somehow. The class and its function is not used by anything other than how its shown in the code.

Comment: If i move the function into the SupportLib and delete the ExtensionFunctions class, the error is stil there referencing the the now non existant ExtensionFunctions and SupportLib.